# JComboBox itemstatechanged event

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, stack-overflow

i have this 2 JComboBoxes
I want that when i select an ID from the first jComboBox
the 2nd jComboBox will automatically select the same index as selected in the first jComboBox.

I had successfully implemented the itemstatechanged of the 1st jcombobox using this code

```
private void driver_select_comboboxItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
   int index1 = driver_select_id_combobox.getSelectedIndex();
   int index2 = driver_select_combobox.getSelectedIndex();
   if( index1 != index2 ){
      driver_select_id_combobox.setSelectedIndex(index2);
   }
}
```

but when i add an itemstatechange event in the 2nd jComboBox with this code

```
private void driver_select_id_comboboxItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
   int index1 = driver_select_id_combobox.getSelectedIndex();
   int index2 = driver_select_combobox.getSelectedIndex();
   if( index1 != index2 ){
       driver_select_combobox.setSelectedIndex(index1);
   }
}
```

i get an error of stackoverflowerror.
that happened because as the 1st jcombobox changes state, it changes the state of the 
2nd jcombobox and as the 2nd jcombobox changes state, it changes the state of the 1st jcombobox. and so on.
so there's no ending to calling the itemstatechanged method.

can anyone please help me how to do this? or do you have any idea on how to implement this?
sorry, im new to java.

Comment: Popular question. You can either create a flag isAPICall. Set it to true in the listener and check in another listener to ignore API calls. Or you can remove the listener before action and readd after.

Comment: sorry i still really dont understand what listener is. still very newbie here :(
can you please explain further. thank you for responding btw. :D

Comment: The listener added to your jcombobox. You can remove it and readd after the action

Comment: Now i get it. thank you sir :D